# How to configure firefox from terminal?

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to configure firefox from terminal?For example if i want to set `toolkit.networkmanager.disable=true` in `about:config` can i do it from terminal?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This setting should go into your Firefox profile **prefs.js** file, which should be located in `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/`.

The file format is JavaScript, so in theory it could be mangled to the point of needing a JS parser to modify it, but Firefox is usually nice and prints each setting on its own line in alphabetical order. To add a setting like this you could simply

```
echo 'user_pref("toolkit.networkmanager.disable", true);' >> ~/.mozilla/firefox/**replace**.default/prefs.js
```

If this setting is already in the file, I'm not sure whether Firefox will register the last or first instance. Just give it a try. If it's not consistent, you could do this:

```
if grep 'toolkit.networkmanager.disable' ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js
then
    sed -i -e 's/^user_pref("toolkit.networkmanager.disable", \(true\|false\));$/user_pref("toolkit.networkmanager.disable", true);/' ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js
else
    echo 'user_pref("toolkit.networkmanager.disable", true);' >> ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js
fi
```

After modifying the configuration you'll need to restart Firefox to apply the change.

Comment: You've ninja'd me and I'm even happy you did as your answer is even better. +1

Comment: do we need to restart firefox after setting this ?